# How to get attribute in the XDocument object

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml

```
<config>
    <audio first="true" second="false" third="true" />
</config>
```

I want my code to able to do something like this

```
if (xdoc.getAttr("first")=="true")
    Console.Write("first is true");
```

How do I do this with LINQ XDocument?
What I have so far is the XDocument Object loaded with that xml string.

Comment: I would answer, but it would be redundant. The operations you want to perform are in XElement.

Comment: @Slaks, i did, but i could not find what i am looking for,
@legatou i ll have a look at XElement.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to get the attribute of the `<audio>` element:

```
string value = xdoc.Root.Element("audio").Attribute("first").Value;
```

Comment: this one is nice. I added Convert.toBoolean(value); to convert it to boolean

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at XElement

[article at c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/xLinkDoc06202007130827PM/xLinkDoc.aspx)