# Yahoo Weather Rss Reading with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, rss

I want to parse yahoo weather rss feed xml in here : http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

My Rss Item

```
public class YahooWeatherRssItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    // temp, wind, etc...
}
```

My Rss Manager

```
public static IEnumerable<YahooWeatherRssItem> GetYahooWeatherRssItems(string rssUrl)
{
    XDocument rssXml = XDocument.Load(rssUrl);

    var feeds = from feed in rssXml.Descendants("item")
                select new YahooWeatherRssItem
                {
                    I can get following values
                    Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                    Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
                    Description = feed.Element("description").Value,

                    // I dont know, How can I parse these.
                    Text = ?
                    Temp = ?
                    Code = ?
                };
        return feeds;
    }
```

I dont know, How Can I parse following xml lines:

```
<yweather:condition  text="Mostly Cloudy"  code="28"  temp="50"  date="Fri, 18 Dec 2009 9:38 am PST" />
<yweather:location city="Sunnyvale" region="CA"   country="United States"/>
<yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
<yweather:wind chill="50"   direction="0"   speed="0" />
<yweather:atmosphere humidity="94"  visibility="3"  pressure="30.27"  rising="1" />
<yweather:astronomy sunrise="7:17 am"   sunset="4:52 pm"/>
```

problem is `yweather:<string>`. There may be an article about xml parsing like this structure. Or code example?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to access the Attribute's - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429903/how-to-get-attribute-in-the-xdocument-object for an example. In your instance, `feed.Element("condition").Attribute("text").Value` for example.

Comment: When I write `string value = xdoc.Root.Element("yweather:condition").Attribute("text").Value;` I got this error : `"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name." string`

Comment: When I write `feed.Element("condition").Attribute("text").Value` I m getting null object refrence error. I debugged it. I m Getting xml file with correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression should work, first reference the `ycweather` namespace;

```
XNamespace yWeatherNS = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0";
```

then you get the attribute values this way:

```
Text = feed.Element(yWeatherNS + "condition").Attribute("text").Value
```

The problem is that your condition element in in another namespace, so you must select this node in the context of that namespace via the [XNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx).

You can read more about XML Namespaces via the MSDN article [Namespaces in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387042.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use namespace and get the data using `Attribute`

```
XNamespace ns = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0";
var feeds = from feed in rssXml.Descendants("item")
            select new YahooWeatherRssItem
            {

                Title = feed.Element("title").Value,
                Link = feed.Element("link").Value,
                Description = feed.Element("description").Value,
                Code=feed.Element(ns+"condition").Attribute("code").Value       
                //like above line, you can get other items 
            };
```

This will work . **TESTED :)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the XML attributes for those values.  Based on the question here ( [Find Elements by Attribute using XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678251/find-elements-by-attribute-using-xdocument) ), you can try something like this:

```
Temp = feed.Attribute("temp");
```

Comment: there is a string before attributes like this: `<yweather:location , <yweather:units , <yweather:wind , etc...` So I cant parse it.