# Deserialize XML with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can I get the `id` attribute of lib into a foreach with C#? I need to do something with each string and I need it in a sort of foreach way? Can anyone help.

```
<map>
  <lib id="blue" revision="58399">
    <part id="2732" type="ch"/>
    <part id="2732" type="ls"/>
    <part id="2732" type="rs"/>
    <part id="2733" type="ch"/>
  </lib>
  <lib id="black" revision="26609">
    <part id="2109" type="cc"/>
    <part id="2109" type="lc"/>
    <part id="2109" type="rc"/>
  </lib>
</map>
```

Heres what I've tried, although it returns null.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(_storagePath + "/file.xml");

foreach (var child in document.Elements())
{
    foreach (var childOfChild in child.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(childOfChild.Element("id").Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far to solve this? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I am new to C# and don't know how to do this, I am asking where do I start?

Comment: You start by taking a class on C#, picking up a book, exploring the namespaces, perusing MSDN...  you don't start at SO.

Comment: You make it sound like I'm serious about this, I'm 14 years old damn man, I'm just making an application for my friend and I don't wish to spend hours on learning all about XML.

Comment: Updated with what I tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429903/how-to-get-attribute-in-the-xdocument-object

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get `id` attribute of `lib` elements.

Here is the common code (xml variable):

```
var xml = @"<map>
             <lib id=""blue"" revision=""58399"">
                 <part id=""2732"" type=""ch""/>
                 <part id=""2732"" type=""ls""/>
                 <part id=""2732"" type=""rs""/>
                 <part id=""2733"" type=""ch""/>
             </lib>
                 <lib id=""black"" revision=""26609"">
                 <part id=""2109"" type=""cc""/>
                 <part id=""2109"" type=""lc""/>
                 <part id=""2109"" type=""rc""/>
             </lib>
           </map>";
```

Here is one:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var lib in xdoc.Descendants("lib"))
    Console.WriteLine(lib.Attribute("id").Value);
```

two:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var item in xdoc.Root.Elements("lib"))
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("id").Value);
```

three (using XPath):

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
foreach (XmlAttribute attr in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/map/lib/@id"))
    Console.WriteLine(attr.Value);
```